# Determining differentiability in given intervals

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The set of points where $ () =\frac {}{1+||}$ is differentiable is

$a. (-∞,0) ∪ (0,∞)$

$b. (-∞,∞) $

$c. (-∞,1) ∪ (1,∞)$

$d. (-∞,∞) \backslash \{-1,0,1\} $

So I first calculated the left-hand and right hand-limits around 0,+∞,-∞,1 and -1.
After finding where it is continuous I started finding out the $\lim \limits_{h \to 0}
\frac {f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ for determining the differentiability.

But I cannot get hold of the differentiability test. According to the solutions, answer should be b. Can someone help me?
[Question available here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mp0Zq.png)

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1776413/42969, or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1226998/42969, or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3129939/42969 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24()%20%3D%5Cfrac%20%7B%7D%7B1%2B%7C%7C%7D%24%2C%20AND%20content%3Adifferentiable)

Answer (score 0):

You have a quotient of continuous functions so first of all look at the denominator, it never vanishes so the function is well defined and continuous over all the real line. For differentiability you only have troubles with the absolute value, which is not differentiable in $x=0$, but the value in the numerator makes the function vanish so $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$. In the rest of the points your function is a quotient of differentiable points, so your domain of differentiability is $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Yeah, it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

### What is differentiability?

In calculus there are two similar properties of functions. Continuity and differentiability. Continuity describes if a function is continuous (duh) and the differentiability describes on which intervals the derivative of the function is continuous.

So, to find the differentiable intervals of a function, you need to test where the first derivative is continuous.

### Finding discontinuities

The easiest way to determine the differentiable intervals here is to simply take the whole number line and rule out the intervals in which it is discontinuous.

For this, you, as said, just calculate the derivative and try finding discontinuities.

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{1+|x|} \\
\text{Quotient rule!}\\
\begin{align*} f'(x) &=\frac{(x)'(1+|x|)-(x)(1+|x|)'}{(1+|x|)^2} \\
&=\frac{1+|x|-x\frac{d|x|}{dx}}{(1+|x|)^2} \\
\text{The derivative of |x| is } \frac{|x|}{x} \text{  !}\\
&=\frac{|x|+1-x \cdot \frac{|x|}{x}}{(1+|x|)^2} \\
f'(x)&=\frac{1}{(1+|x|)^2}
\end{align*}
$$

Now that we have done the calculation of the derivative, let's check for discontinuities. For that, we should check where the function is not defined:

1. Is there some calculation that involved a step that is only valid for certain numbers?
   Yes! In the process of deriving we used the derivative of |x| which involved dividing by x ! Here we find that the function is not defined, and therefore not continuous, at x=0.
2. Is the denominator of our fraction sometimes equal to 0 ?
   Well, let's take a look.
   $(1+|x|)^2=0$
   Pretty quickly you can see that this is only true if |x|=-1, which never happens in the real numbers.

Wrapping up, you can see that the only discontinuity is x=0, wherefore the answer should be a).

If the given solutions say that the answer is b), then they seem to have ignored that the derivative should not be defined at x=0. Could you send those said solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The only potential problem point is at $x=0$, where $y = |x|$ on it's own is not differentiable, so $f$ *might* not be differentiable. The easiest way to resolve this is to remember that absolute value can be written as a piecewise function:
$$
x = \begin{cases} 
\hfil x, & x \geq 0, \\ 
-x, & x < 0. 
\end{cases}
$$
Notice that either formula works for $x=0$, so I've lumped it in with the positive inputs. Your function now looks like
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
\frac{x}{1+x}, & x \geq 0, \\[2pt] 
\frac{x}{1-x}, & x < 0. 
\end{cases}
$$
Using standard formulas for differentiation,
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}, & x \geq 0, \\[2pt] 
\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}, & x < 0, 
\end{cases}
$$
which can be recombined for convenience into one formula:
$$
f'(x) = \frac{1}{(1+|x|)^2}. 
$$
This function is defined for all real numbers, including $x=0$, where $f'(0) = 1$.

---

It's interesting to note that if we differentiate one more time, we do run into a problem at $x=0$, as
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
-\frac{2}{(1+x)^3}, & x > 0, \\[2pt] 
\hfil \frac{2}{(1-x)^3}, & x < 0, 
\end{cases}
$$
but there's no meaningful way to define $f''(0)$. Hence, the function is not second-differentiable.